# Remove unmatched values from a string in a pipe delimited file

Tags: unix, awk

I have an input file with columns delimited by `|`

Input File:

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2;TEST_M1
CRIC2|ODI_M1;IPL_M3
CRIC3|ODI_M3;TEST_M5
CRIC4|IPL_M5;ODI_M5;IPL_M;RANGI_M1
CRIC5|RANGI_M1
```

Output should change only in COL2 no other columns should change, i,e in COL2 the string which has 'IPL_' should populate,
other than 'IPL_' needs to populate as null and remove unwanted semicolons. COL2 may contains as many as values(both IPL and non IPL values)

Expected Output:

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M6
CRIC5|
```

Tried this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS="|" '{$2=($2!="IPL_%")?" ":$2}1' File.txt
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Tried below one but it is not working

 `awk -F, -vOFS="|" '{$2=($2!="IPL_%")?" ":$2}1' File.txt`

Comment: Include your attempt in your question along with a statement of in what way it's "not working".

Answer (score 1):

As all the cool awk answers were already taken, I started playing around with PCRE lookaround so, if you can use perl, here is one for that:

```
perl -p -e 's/(?<=(\|)|(;))[^I][^P][^L][^;\n]*(;|(\n))|/\4/g if $.>1;s/;$//' file
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```

**Edit:** Testing a bit with shorter than 3 strings (`FO`):

```
$ cat foo
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2;TEST_M1;FO;FO
CRIC2|ODI_M1;IPL_M3;FO;FO
CRIC3|FO;ODI_M3;TEST_M5
CRIC4|FO;IPL_M5;FO;ODI_M5;IPL_M;RANGI_M1
CRIC5|FO;RANGI_M1
```

outputs

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M           # fails if <3 preceeds a match 
CRIC5|
```

So yeah, it fails. This seems to work a bit better (changed to: `[^I;\n][^P;\n]?[^L;\n]?`):

```
$ perl -p -e 's/(?<=(\|)|(;))[^I;\n][^P;\n]?[^L;\n]?[^;\n]*(;|(\n))|/\4/g 
  if $.>1;
  s/;$//' foo
```

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } 
{
    n=split($2,a,";")
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(a[i]~/^IPL/||NR==1)
            b=b (b==""?"":";") a[i]
    print $1,b;b=""
}' file
```

outputs:

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```

Comment: Gotta comment later, emergency at hands.

Comment: what if you have less than 3 characters field in 2nd column? ;)

Comment: @Sundeep It fails.

Comment: you can simplify it to `perl -lpe 's/(?<=[|;])[^I;][^P;]?[^L;]?[^;]*;?//g if $.>1; s/;$//'` but I still don't think this is robust.. anyway, welcome to perl world :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|"; sfs=";" }
    NR>1 {
        n = split($2,f,sfs)
        $2 = ""
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            if (f[i] ~ /^IPL_/) {
                $2 = ($2=="" ? "" : $2 sfs) f[i]
            }
        }
    }
    { print }
' file
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -lane '$F[1] = join ";", grep {/IPL_/} split /;/,$F[1] if $.>1;
                     print join "|", @F' ip.txt
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```

- `-F'\|' -lane` See [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for details. Here, `|` is set as input field separator and results are available from `@F` array
- `if $.>1` if input line number is greater than 1

  - `split /;/,$F[1]` split the second input field on `;`
  - `grep {/IPL_/}` filter only elements containing `IPL_` from split output. Use regex anchors if needed
  - `join ";"` use `;` to join the output of `grep` and then save the results back to second element of `@F` array
- `print join "|", @F` and then print elements of `@F` array with `|` as separator

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -E '
  1b
  s/\|/\|;/
  s/IPL_M/@/g
  s/;[^@][^;]*//g
  s/\|;/\|/
  s/@/IPL_M/g
' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "|" }
     NR == 1;
     NR > 1{
         len = split($2, a, ";");
         res = "";
         for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
             if (a[i] ~ /^IPL_/) res = res (res != ""? ";" : "") a[i];
         print $1, res
     }' file.txt
```

The output:

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` variation:

```
awk -F '|' '
    NR == 1 { print; next }
    {
        split($2, a, ";")
        s = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= length(a); ++i)
            if (a[i] ~ /^IPL_/)
                s = s a[i] ";"
        print $1, substr(s, 1, length(s)-1)
    }' OFS='|' file
```

which generates

```
COL1|COL2
CRIC1|IPL_M1;IPL_M2
CRIC2|IPL_M3
CRIC3|
CRIC4|IPL_M5;IPL_M
CRIC5|
```